# How to quickly check if a value exists in pandas DataFrame index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I update the `dataframe`, I should check if the value exists in the `dataframe` index, but I want to know **which way is faster**, thanks!

`1. if value in set(dataframe.index)
2. if value in dataframe.index`

Comment: Waht is type of index? `numeric`? `datetimeindex` ?

Comment: The type for the dataframe.index is 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'.

Comment: And index values are duplicated? `print (df.index.has_duplicates)` ?

Comment: No.  I'm not sure  the assert 'value in dataframe.index' will use hashtable under the hood.

Comment: The first time you do `value in df.index`, it creates a hash table for later use. So the first search might be relatively slow but the subsequent ones will be very fast. Converting into a set will do a similar thing but you'll go back and forth between different data structures.

Comment: @ayhan Thanks a lot, u interpret it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need second solution:

```
value in dataframe.index
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(100000)})
df.index = df.index.astype(np.int64)
print (df.index)


In [64]: %timeit (5000 in df.index)
The slowest run took 37.76 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 523 ns per loop

In [65]: %timeit (5000 in df.index.values)
The slowest run took 5.24 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 76.7 µs per loop

In [66]: %timeit (5000 in set(df.index))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.34 ms per loop
```

**Timimgs** for more data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(100000)})
df.index = df.index.astype(np.int64)

np.random.seed(2017)
a = np.random.randint(100000, size=1000)

In [73]: %timeit ([i in df.index for i in a])
The slowest run took 4.36 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 636 µs per loop

In [74]: %timeit ([i in df.index.values for i in a])
1 loop, best of 3: 208 ms per loop

In [75]: %timeit ([i in set(df.index) for i in a])
1 loop, best of 3: 7.44 s per loop
```

Comment: Why are turning a hash table to a regular array? Wouldn't it be way slower?

Comment: The type(dataframe.index.values) is numpy.ndarray, which maybe a (random access) list, not a hash set.

Comment: Awesome. great!

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be.

a=time.time()
if value in set(dataframe.index)
b=time.time()
timetaken=b-a